# In Nginx, how do you configure a split redirect?

Tags: redirect, configuration, nginx

I want to configure Nginx so that this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/x/...
```

redirects here:

```
http://x.example.com/...
```

and everything else (not http://www.example.com/x/...)

```
http://www.example.com/...
```

remains as-is:

```
http://www.example.com/...
```

How do you configure Nginx to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you do os by setting up 2 location blocks inside your server config: 1 with the redirect, and 1 with the default stuff that matches anything else like so:

```
location / {
   # directives needed to serve the regular stuff       
}

location /x/ {
  rewrite ^/x/(.*)$ $1 last;
}
```